# Creating custom fragment in Cumulocity

Tags: cumulocity

Is it possible to create custom fragment as below?

```
"custom_Position": {
    "alt": 67,
    "lng": 6.15173,
    "lat": 51.211977,
    "place":"xxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the default fragments like c8y_Position can also be extended. So you can do something like this.

```
"c8y_Position": {
    "alt": 67,
    "lng": 6.15173,
    "lat": 51.211977,
    "place":"xxxx"
}
```

Then the default map widget still works (of course it won't show the place).

But in general as said already you can add fragments in any shape you want. This is also true for the other data APIs like measurements, events, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A device can add any custom fragment they want in the managed object. The only drawback is that the widgets (the map widget for example in your case) will not work out of the box with your new fragment.